# Why list ++ requires to scan all elements of list on its left?

Tags: performance, list, haskell, concatenation

The Haskell tutorial says, be cautious that when we use "Hello"++" World", the new list construction has to visit all single elements(here, every character of "Hello"), so if the list on the left of "++" is long, then using "++" will bring down performance.

I think I was not understanding correctly, does Haskell's developers never tune the performance of list operations? Why this operation remains slow, to have some kind of syntax consistencies in any lambda function or currying?

Any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In some languages, a "list" is a general-purpose sequence type intended to offer good performance for concatenation, splitting, etc. In Haskell, and most traditional functional languages, a list is a very specific data structure, namely a singly-linked list. If you want a general-purpose sequence type, you should use `Data.Sequence` from the `containers` package (which is already installed on your system and offers very good big-O asymptotics for a wide variety of operations), or perhaps some other one more heavily optimized for common usage patterns.

Comment: Do you mean that Data.Sequence is a mutable type, so that it maintains a pointer/indicator to its tail?

Comment: @HindForsum Technically Data.Sequence is a *tree*, so it has logarithmic complexity for most operations. But it's a finger-tree, so concatenation is especially fast. There's nothing mutable about it.

Comment: @HindForsum, no. It is immutable and represented by a 2-3 finger tree. This offers access, modification, and splitting in time proportional to the logarithm of the distance to the nearer end, concatenation in time logarithmic in the length of the shorter sequence, and a number of other pleasant things. Go take a look, read the paper, play with it, etc. Get a reasonably recent version for my own modest contributions.

Answer (score 4):

If you have immutable list which has a head and a reference to the tail, you cannot change its tail. If you want to add something to the 'end' of the list, you have to reach the end and then put all items one by one to the head of your right list. It is the fundamential property of immutable lists: concatenation is expensive.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell lists are like singly-linked lists: they are either empty or they consist of a head and a (possibly empty) tail. Hence, when appending something to a list, you'll first have to walk the entire list to get to the end. So you end up traversing the entire list (the list to which you append, that is), which needs O(n) runtime.

Comment: *they consist of a head [...]* What about the empty list?

Comment: Well, empty lists have no head (duh). I mentioned that explicitly now.

Comment: I was just nitpicking `:)`

Comment: On concatenation, a copy of the "left list" is done and already traversed to the end of it, then concat the "right list". There's no extra traversing, how can it be slow?

Comment: @HindForsum There is no extra traversing other than the one you need to do while copying the left list.